# Timer with interval of multiple months

Tags: c#, timer

I have a windows service handles events triggered by a System.Timers.Timer.
I want to set the interval of that timer to 3 months.

The Interval property of the System.Timers.Timer is an Int32 in millseconds, and Int32.MaxValue is smaller than 3 months in milliseconds.

What should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would re-think your design. Store the next time you want to execute your event (e.g. registry, file, database, ...) and then wake up periodically to check whether that time has passed. Even if you could set a System.Timers.Timer for 3 months, the system would likely reboot before the timer went off and you'd lose your event.

Another option would be to use a scheduled job executed by the Windows Scheduler. It would run a small program that sends your service a message saying that the event has occurred. This would be less resource intensive - though more complex - than waking up periodically to check whether the 3 months had elapsed.

Comment: Design re-thought, and now a timer checks a NextExecuteTime property. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run your PC for continuously for 3 month. If application is closed timer will also close. On restarting application results the timer to restart from beginning.

If you want to fire event at interval of 3 months you must keep information about the total time elapsed by the  timer at the time of exiting application.

**Updated**

So you have to divide your interval in some parts and set a counter on every elapse and increment it.Check it in every elapse until it reaches to 3 months.

**e.g.**

```
    int interval = 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Time interval for 10 days 
    int counter = 0;
    private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 9) 
        {
            //do your task for 3 months
            //since counter increments 9 times at interval of 10 days
            //so 9*10=90 days i.e. nearly equal to 3 months
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As I mentioned, this is for a windows service, not an application, and so I do expect this service to be running continuously for several months. Thank you for your comment though.

Comment: Do you honestly expect a Windows machine to stay up reliably for 3+ months at a time? Even without crashes, critical security updates are released the require a reboot every few months. Take a look at the uptime stats http://uptime.netcraft.com/up/today/top.avg.html and http://uptime.netcraft.com/up/today/requested.html. Many systems have uptimes measured in weeks and the best ones in months.

Comment: @JamesKovacs That is irrelevant if the timer is set to trigger at a specific _precalculated date_. It just happens to need a time _span_, though. You'd want a system to _rely_ on downtime and reboots just to function right?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Quartz.net - the opensource enterprise job scheduler - http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

You may use CRON like syntax- http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_6.html
& you may store relevant job state to a DB easily (just incase the machine dies, which it will) - http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_9.html, and lots more usefulness.

I've used Quartz.net on several production systems and to my knowledge the processes are still running today :)

Why not use System.Timer - http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/faq.html#whynottimer

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, except that it was a generic system that could do the same thing with completely adjustable intervals, from milliseconds to months. Well, was *supposed* to. Turned out it indeed messed up on intervals larger than 24.8 days because of this.

In my case, "rethinking the approach" was of out of the question, since it was just one small problem sub-case of a much larger Windows service system.

The solution was rather simple, but do note I had a side system that supplied me with the next execution as `DateTime`; the timer's job was just to match that to actually execute the task, so it calculated the interval simply by subtracting `DateTime.Now` from that.

In this case, all I needed to do was keep an overflow boolean alongside my timer object, and setting that when checking that interval against `Int32.MaxValue`:

```
private Timer _timer;
private Boolean _overflow;

private void QueueNextTime(DateTime thisTime)
{
    TimeSpan interval = this.NextRunTime(thisTime) - DateTime.Now;
    // Not using TotalMilliseconds since it adds an extra conversion to Double.
    Int64 intervalMilliSeconds = interval.Ticks / 10000;
    if (intervalMilliSeconds <= 0)
        intervalMilliSeconds = 1;
    // If interval greater than Int32.MaxValue, set the boolean to skip the next
    // run. The interval will be topped at Int32.MaxValue. The TimerElapsed
    // function will call this function again anyway, so no need to store any
    // information on how much is left. It'll just repeat until the overflow
    // status is 'false'.
    bool wasOverflow = this._overflow;
    this._overflow = intervalMilliSeconds > Int32.MaxValue;
    this._timer.Interval = Math.Min(intervalMilliSeconds, Int32.MaxValue);
    if (!wasOverflow)
    {
        // Execution actually occurred. Save time.
        this._lastTime = thisTime;
    }
    this._timer.Start();
}

// The function linked to _timer.Elapsed
private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this._timer.Stop();
    if (this._overflow)
    {
        QueueNextTime(e.SignalTime);
        return;
    }

    // Execute tasks
    // ...
    // ...

    // schedule next execution, based on when this execution run started.
    QueueNextTime(e.SignalTime);
}

// Amount of days between executions.
private Int32 _intervalDays;
// Offset time inside day. Is prepared in advance to be lower than a full day.
private Int32 _offsetInDay;
// Last time the operation was executed.
private DateTime _lastTime;

// The actual system I used was more advanced in choices of interval and
// offset types (could do stuff like "12th of each month"), but this is
// the basic gist of it, simplified to "every x days, at HH:mm:ss".
// The value of "_offsetInDay" is prepared in advance.
private DateTime NextRunTime(DateTime lastRunTime)
{
    // Take start of execution day as basis.
    DateTime next = new DateTime(_lastTime.Year, _lastTime.Month, _lastTime.Day);
    // start of day after current run day.
    DateTime afterLastRunDay =
        new DateTime(lastRunTime.Year, lastRunTime.Month, lastRunTime.Day)
        .AddDays(1);
    // Full system can load "_lastTime" from settings to resume after a cold
    // start. The loop ensures the schedule is retained as if it never stopped.
    while (next <= afterLastRunDay)
    {
        next = next.AddDays(_intervalDays);
    }
    return next.AddMilliseconds(_offsetInDay);
}
```

This is simplified, of course; the real system has try/catch and a system to abort on external stop commands. But that's the gist of it.

Comment: this worked great!  I did not want to rework `ol' thicc boy` windows service, but recently business wanted a single job to run few months out.  slap another bubble gum in the code to hold it together and ship it!!

Answer (score 0):

I would create an exe application and run as a part of scheduled Windows Task.